# Read a file in bash, execute query in MongoDB and add result in the last column in a while loop

Tags: mongodb, bash, mongodb-query, concatenation

I have a TSV file that has 111 columns and 20k lines. I perform a while loop to read each line, query on particular column in MongoDB and retrieve my result. The issue is that neither `awk` or `echo` or `cat` or `tr` or `sed` works when I try to add the result at the end of my line. My query retrieves the count of the `find` function of MongoDB. It returns only a number.

```
sed '1d' 10206.SNP.txt | while read line; do 
    array=($line)
    valquery=$(mongo --quiet  TestDatabase --eval "db.TestCollection.find( {\"Chromosome\": \"${array[0]}\", \"Position\": ${array[1]}, \"Reference\": \"${array[3]}\", \"Mutation\": \"${array[4]}\"} ).count()")
    stuff="$line$valquery"
    echo $stuff
done
```

or

```
sed '1d' 10206.SNP.txt | while read line; do 
    array=($line)
    valquery=$(mongo --quiet  TestDatabase --eval "db.TestCollection.find( {\"Chromosome\": \"${array[0]}\", \"Position\": ${array[1]}, \"Reference\": \"${array[3]}\", \"Mutation\": \"${array[4]}\"} ).count()")
    echo "$line" | awk -v val=$valquery '{gsub("\n",X,$0); print $0"\n"val}'
done

sed '1d' 10206.SNP.txt | while read line; do 
    array=($line)
    valquery=$(mongo --quiet  TestDatabase --eval "db.TestCollection.find( {\"Chromosome\": \"${array[0]}\", \"Position\": ${array[1]}, \"Reference\": \"${array[3]}\", \"Mutation\": \"${array[4]}\"} ).count()")
    echo "$line" | awk -v val=$valquery '{print $0"\t"val}'
done
```

or

```
sed '1d' 10206.SNP.txt | while read line; do 
    array=($line)
    valquery=$(mongo --quiet  TestDatabase --eval "db.TestCollection.find( {\"Chromosome\": \"${array[0]}\", \"Position\": ${array[1]}, \"Reference\": \"${array[3]}\", \"Mutation\": \"${array[4]}\"} ).count()") && echo -e "$line" | tr -d '\n' | awk -v val=$valquery '{print $0"\t"val}'
done
```

After redirecting the results of my query in a file, I get something like:

```
chr1    ... lotsofcolumns ...   0.8481 0.9018 0.9983 gnomAD_EAS
    293 // The query result
chr1    ... lotsofcolumns ...   0.9854 0.9995 gnomAD_EAS
    997 // The query result
chr1    ... lotsofcolumns...    0.9314 0.9441 gnomAD_EAS
    2 // The query result
```

I would like to output the result on the same line for each row like:

```
chr1    ... lotsofcolumns ...   0.8481 0.9018 0.9983 gnomAD_EAS 293
chr1    ... lotsofcolumns ...   0.9854 0.9995 gnomAD_EAS    997 
chr1    ... lotsofcolumns...    0.9314 0.9441 gnomAD_EAS    2
```

Comment: Seems there is a carriage return in query result. Remove it with `sed -i 's/\r$//g' qr`

Comment: @RemisaYousefvand thanks for your answer but the carriage return was in the `$line` itself. Using your `sed` command, I was able to print it correctly.

Comment: glad to hear that. gl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The carriage return was actually in the `$line` itself. But thanks to @RemisaYousefvand, the solution is the following:

```
sed '1d' 10206.SNP.txt | while read line; do 
    array=($line)
    valquery=$(mongo --quiet  TestDatabase --eval "db.TestCollection.find( {\"Chromosome\": \"${array[0]}\", \"Position\": ${array[1]}, \"Reference\": \"${array[3]}\", \"Mutation\": \"${array[4]}\"} ).count()")
    line2=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/\r$//g')
    echo -e "$line2\t$valquery"
done
```